# npm install express fails. ENETUNREACH Error

Tags: node.js, npm, registry

I've been trying to install express on raspberry pi for a couple hours now. Not real sure what the issue is.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm -v
8.1.0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node -v
v17.0.1

pi@raspberrypi:~/Project-Folder $ npm install

up to date, audited 1 package in 803ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

npm install works fine, but when I try to reach the registry it fails.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Project-Folder $ npm install -g express
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.com/express failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 0000:0000::0000:0000:80

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2021-10-26T17_22_03_292Z-debug.log
```

it doesn't actually have that ip address I just don't want to leak any thing.

I've done everything below.

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` - Failed

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/` - Failed

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` - Failed

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.com/` - Failed

`npm cache clean` - Failed

nslookup returns the following

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nslookup registry.npmjs.org
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.24.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.26.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.19.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.25.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.20.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.23.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.18.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.27.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.21.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.16.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.22.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 104.16.17.35
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1923
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1823
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1123
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1623
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1023
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1723
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1423
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1223
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1b23
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1523
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1323
Name:   registry.npmjs.org
Address: 2606:4700::6810:1a23
```

I have looked around for quite a bit and it seems like everyone fixes the issue by changing there registry. That doesn't work for me.

This is not a network issue. Below is from MacBook Pro same network.

```
username Project-Folder % npm install -g express

added 50 packages, and audited 51 packages in 2s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73829204/1074998) to set `$NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being that my local network didn't support IPv6, so I just needed to disable it on my raspberry pi and the issue was fixed.

To check if IPv6 is enabled.

use `ifconfig`

if it contains `inet6` then IPv6 is enabled

to disable

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

Add this to the end:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Add this to the end (but before “exit 0”):

`service procps reload`

Reboot the Pi

`sudo reboot`

use `ifconfig` and look for `inet6` if it doesn't appear then IPv6 is disabled