# how to fix connect ENETUNREACH on npm on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-registry

i am not using a proxy im just a noob trying to learn how to develop with `create-react-app` locally on my machine(linux)

this is the output of `tracepath registry.npmjs.org`

```
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                        0.020ms pmtu 1500
 1:  2001:4451:664:1400:caf6:c8ff:fef2:bdcb                2.906ms !N
 1:  2001:4451:664:1400:caf6:c8ff:fef2:bdcb                0.995ms !N
     Resume: pmtu 1500
```

i think this proves im not using a proxy.

but i keep getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
```

for anything npm. i dont know what to do.

i have tried..

1. deleting the package.json in my home directory. deleting the
2. package-lock.json in my home directory. deleting the .npm directory
   in my home direcory.
3. clearing the cache with the npm config command
4. setting https-proxy from the config to null setting proxy from the
5. config to null setting the registry to https://registry.npmjs.org
6. setting the registry to htpp://registry.npmjs.org uninstalled npm
7. and dependencies then reinstalled unintsalled npm and dependencies then installed nvm and reinstalled node through that

`npm install --verbose` doesnt say any error messages

please somebody help me, i try just about anything shy of reinstalling my os.

Comment: The output of `tracepath` has nothing to do with whether or not you are using a proxy. A proxy will only be used by specific applications for specific protocols. The use of a proxy could be influence by both environment variables and application-specific configuration files (and they question of "proxy or not" may be entirely irrelevant).

Comment: i dont know.. from googling a bunch many of the solutions i found was to configure the correct proxy in npm config. but i dont think i need to be doing that

Answer (score 34):

The issue is that node 18 (not happening on 16) is trying to resolve by ipv6 first.

Can override it by exporting the environment variable:

`export NODE_OPTIONS="--dns-result-order=ipv4first"`

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem for myself by temporarily disabling IPv6.

On Linux here is the command I used:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and the above answers were not solving it. What I did is uninstalled everything and then installed all using **NVM**, which fixed the issue.

Comment: Please provide more information on how to accomplish this.